# Facebook errors related to auth.extendSSOAccessToken

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, sdk3.0

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android in my app to post updates on peoples walls. In my Insights area of facebook, it says that about 25% of my API calls are resulting in an API error. Under the 'most common API error' it says `auth.extendSSOAccessToken`. Under the 'API error breakdown' it says no API errors.

The only time I see `auth.extendSSOAccessToken` referenced in the Facebook developer site is an old bug that has been fixed. I've checked the token expiry date and they are being set to expire after 2 months so any tokens generated haven't had a chance to expire.

I am assuming that somewhere the session is requesting to extend the single sign on access token but I don't know why. I also don't know if this error is restricting people from signing on. I am not able to replicate this error on my own testing device so I am left with the limited information provided on the Facebook insights page.

Anyone familiar with this error and know how to prevent it?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, but since its not affecting performance, as far as I can tell, I just left it.

Comment: Take a look at your Key Hashes, it should be in developer.facebook.com under apps, click on 'Edit Apps' at the top right and take a look at Native Android App. I think that a released build and a build under debug uses different Key Hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this type of error, but there is a new SDK 3.5, you could give it a try :-).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/